# Firebase Database rule - update only specific fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a structure like this :

```
posts: {
    group:{
        postId: {
          nbLikes: ..,
          nbComments: ...,
          updatedAt: ...,
          text: ...
        }
    }
 }
```

and I would like to allow the author to remove it, and everyone else to update everything except the text. 
I have tried with this:

```
  "posts": {
    "$group": {
      "$post": {
        ".write": "(data.exists() && !newData.exists() && data.child('userId').val() === auth.uid)
        || (data.exists() && newData.exists() && auth.uid != null)
        || (!data.exists() && newData.child('userId').val() === auth.uid)",
        "text": {
          ".write": false
        }

      },
    }

  },
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Moreover, when I try doing,

```
 "posts": {
    "$group": {
      "$post": {
        "text": {
          ".write": false
        },
        "nbLikes": {
          ".write": true
        },
        "nbComments": {
          ".write": true
        }
         ....

      },
    }

  },
```

it doesn't work either

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In your data structure, the `group` property is a dynamic key (id) or a static name property? Because if it's a static name, them in the security rules you have to remove the `$` symbol: `"posts": { "group": { "$post": { ....`

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, it is a dynamic key

Comment: Hmmm... Another reason can be if you have rules between `"rules"` and `"posts"` and they can overwrite the nested rules. For example: `{"rules:{ ".write": true, ".read": true, "posts: {.....}}}`